# Customized operation on two NumPy arrays with standard scalar product structure

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, product, customization

Is there a way to exploit the standard scalar product structure between two arrays in a customized way?

To make it more understandable, I would like to use this type of operation:

```
arr1 = array([a1, b1])
arr2 = array([a2, b2])
scalar_product = arr1@arr2
```

-> where scalar_product is equal to: a1 * a2 + b1 * b2

But instead of '*' and '+' between elements, I would like to use some of my own special methods of addition and multiplication, so it would be something like:

`some_special_scalar_product(arr1, arr2) = my_sum(my_mult(a1, a2), my_mult(b1, b2))`

Extra information:

- The actual inputs of the arrays are strings, and it has to stay strings (for further context the strings are byte representation of Galois Field elements, though it is not essential to understand what it means to answer my question. Just consider that it does make sense in my case to talk about some special sum and multiplication on strings).
- The reason why I would like to do that is to use the efficiency of NumPy operations rater than going for some inefficient 'for loops' with my customized methods. So only solutions matching this efficiency criteria (if possible at all) should be considered.
- If this is not possible, do you have any other suggestion to do this type of operation efficiently? (best ways of storing the strings and accessing them in this situation, etc...)

For full details, I have those classes and functions (last part of 'encode()' method is—as I indicate in comments—where I would like to use the customized dot product):

```
class BinaryDomains():

    def add(self, x, y):
        return format(int(x, base=2)^int(y, base=2), '08b')  # Use bitwise XOR operator

    def multiply(self, x, y):
        prod = 0
        P_ = 0b10100110                  # P_ = irreducible polynomial without last bit (stay on 8 bits)

        #string -> byte:
        x = int(x, base=2)
        y = int(y, base=2)

        while y != 0:
            if y & 1:                    # y has a d°0:
                prod ^= x                # Add with XOR

            if x & 0b10000000:           # x is d°7:
                x = ((x ^ P_) << 1) ^ 1  # Reduce with XOR, increase degree, turn last bit into 1 (missing part of P_)
            else:
                x <<= 1                  # Increase degree

            y >>= 1                      # Get rid of y0 coefficient, decrease degree

        return format(prod, '08b')

class ReedSolomon():

    def __init__(self, k, n, x):
        """
        Args:
            k (int): dimension of message to transmit
            n (int): size of the bloc to transmit
            x (liste de string de taille n): points xi
        """
        self.f = BinaryDomains()
        self.k = k
        self.n = n
        self.x = x

    def encoding(self, message_original):
        bd = self.f
        lst = []

        for i in range(self.n):          # Put xi's powers in a list
            x = self.x[i]
            xpow = x
            lst.append([x])
            for j in range(2, self.k):
                x = bd.multiply(xpow, x)
                lst[i].append(x)

        A = []

        # **** This is where I would like to use some
        #      customised form of dot product:
        #
        for i in range(self.n): # Encode single input with xi's powers -> multiple coded outputs
            A.append(message_original[0])
            for j in range(1, self.k):
                A[i] = bd.add(A[i],
                              bd.multiply(message_original[j], lst[i][j-1]))

        return A
```

Once again, I can't change type of method inputs/outputs (even though it seems silly) and can't import anything else than NumPy.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to [write your own ufunc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html).

Comment: You also might want to consider switching over to Sage, which [comes with built-in functionality to handle Galois Field extensions](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/number_field/number_field.html)

Comment: I didn't know anything about ufunc before you mentioned them. I'm a bit new to coding so feeling a little lost there. Is it anything that can be easily implemented? I mean, the efficiency issues of my problem aren't that much of a big deal that I would go trough anything crazy for it. I just felt that the solution I'm asking for would be so right and convenient if it did exist in a pretty much straightforward way.

Comment: Sadly I can only import numpy in python in my situation. But I will remember that for further cases ! (looks interresting)

Comment: One potentially convenient solution is to use matrix representations of your field elements so that standard operations can essentially be implemented using block-matrices

Comment: I could clarify a bit if you could edit your post to provide and example of the kind of thing that you're trying to do for me to implement.

Comment: Do you have some kind of table of irreducible polynomials over the relevant base field that you can pull information from?

Comment: I work on a single base field : GF(2^8) and with a unique irreducible polynomial P(X) = X^8 + X^6 + X^3 + X^2 +1 . The main post was edited as you asked

Comment: `numpy` operations are efficient when they use compiled code, which works with standard `c` numeric types.  `@` in particular uses highly optimized numeric libraries (`BLAS` etc).    Processing of arrays containing custom object classes is takes place at interpreted list speeds.  `@` can work on object dtype arrays if the elements implement `add` and `multiply` methods - but it won't be fast.

Comment: A quick web search on `galois` produced a link to a custom library in `pipy`, https://pypi.org/project/galois/.  It describes itself as `Internally, the finite field arithmetic is implemented by replacing NumPy ufuncs. The new ufuncs are written in pure Python and just-in-time compiled with Numba.`.  `numba` is a tool for writing custom compiled code that work with Python and `numpy`.

Comment: thank you for that precision about the @ operator, it then couldn't work as I'd like. Again, I can't use extra libraries (it's a project for school, we have instructions), but I guess I get the main idea about how it is done there

Comment: If you rename the `BinaryDomains` methods to `__add__` and `__mul__` you might able to use object dtype arrays containing those objects in `np.dot` or `@`, but I wouldn't expect much speed improvement over your existing code.

Comment: Exactly was I was looking for at first ! Too bad it won't improve efficiency :( thanks though

Comment: @c.leblanc You might be interested in the [galois package](https://pypi.org/project/galois/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is based on [companion matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) and some clever linear algebra. I believe it works correctly, but I will leave it to you to find some examples to error check my method.

```
import numpy as np

class GF8(object):

    def __init__(self):
        poly_coeff = np.array([1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0],dtype = int)
        C = np.block([[np.zeros(7,dtype = int),poly_coeff[0]],[np.eye(7,dtype = int),poly_coeff[1:,None]]])
        self.C = C
        current = np.eye(8,dtype = int)
        _pows = [current]
        for _ in range(7):
            current = current@C%2
            _pows.append(current)

        self.pows = np.stack(_pows)

    def to_mat(self,x):
        return np.sum([M for i,M in enumerate(self.pows) if (1<<i)&x],axis=0)%2

    def to_vec(self,x):
        return np.array([int(bool((1<<i)&x)) for i in range(8)])

    def row_rep(self,arr):
        return np.block([self.to_mat(x) for x in arr])

    def col_rep(self,arr):
        return np.hstack([self.to_vec(x) for x in arr])

    def dot(self,arr_1, arr_2):
        vec_result = self.row_rep(arr_1)@self.col_rep(arr_2)%2
        return sum(b<<i for b,i in enumerate(vec_result))
```

The following test script

```
field = GF8()
ans = field.dot([0b00000111,0b00000110,0b00000101],[0b10000001,0b10000000,0b01111111])
print(format(ans,'08b'))
```

yields the printed answer `00100101`.

Comment: Thank you for spending time on this. In the current case, I couldn't rework everything the way I wanted (it was an assignment for school and we had to respect a structure). But I will get back to your message when I am facing a similar problem while being fully free to write it the way I want.