# Is there an easy way to evaluate an outer product with an "arbitrary function" in python or its standard libraries?

Tags: python, numpy, similarity, array-broadcasting, outer-product

I have a 20x20 grid of pixels. Each of these pixels has coordinates (i,j), where i and j both go from 0 to 19.

I would like to make a 400x400 similarity matrix `C` of these pixels, where if pixel `p` has coordinates `(i,j)` and pixel `q` has coordinates `(k,l)`, then `C[p,q]` has the similarity score of `p` and `q`.

For my similarity score, I'm using the rbf kernel.

It feels like there should be some clever way using broadcasting to create this matrix `C` without using for loops.

For example, if `pixels` was a 400x2 array consisting of the coordinates of the 400 pixels, then the "outer product" `pixels @ pixels.T` would have dimension 400x400 (thought it would consist of the wrong values).

The only different between `pixels @ pixels.T` and what I would like to do is the similarity function I'm applying to the different rows of `pixels`. In the matrix multiplication case, it's an inner product. I would just like to apply the rbf kernel (which takes in two vectors, and outputs a scalar).

Is there a particularly elegant or efficient way to do this in python or its core libraries (numpy, scipy)?

Here's what I'm currently doing, but the for loops annoy me:

```
def sqeuclidean_distance(x, y):
    return np.sum((x-y)**2)

# RBF Kernel
def rbf_kernel(x, y, length_scale=1e1):
    return np.exp( -sqeuclidean_distance(x, y) / (length_scale ** 2))

def make_cov_mat(d):
    x = np.arange(d)
    pixels = np.array([e for e in itertools.product(*[x,x])])
    cov_mat = np.zeros((d**2, d**2))
    for i in range(d**2):
        for j in range(d**2):
            cov_mat[i,j] = rbf_kernel(pixels[i, :], pixels[j, :])
    return cov_mat
```

Comment: Maybe: "https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html"

Comment: @Joao_PS but this doesn't allow for an arbitrary function right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74212034/customized-operation-on-2-numpy-arrays-with-standard-scalar-product-structure explores calculations with a class that has custom `__add__` and `__mul__` methods.

Comment: Think of `numpy` as a Lego set - it's easy and fast to use the pieces it provides, but it does not supply a injection molding machine to create custom shapes.  `numpy` has standard numeric operators and `ufuncs` that are fast because they use compiled `C` code working with standard numeric types.  There's a lot we can do with some clever thinking, but at some point you have to either accept the slow speed of Python loops, or do your own "compilation" using tools like `cython` or `numba`.